# Could you make a system that exchanges matter but no thermodynamic energy?

Tags: thermodynamics

Normally we distinguish between open, closed and isolated systems,  assuming that the 4th possibility does not exist,  as an exchange of matter presupposes energy exchange. Could it be nevertheless possible to build walls that only allow matter exchange under the condition of the energy of the system remaining constant?

If so,  are there some notable examples? (I could think of cell walls with specific enzymes that could carry out that function for whatever reason).

Comment: Perhaps, but I doubt the entropy of such a system would remain constant.

Comment: Energy matter equivalence would seem to preclude this! ;)

Comment: @Dai that's why I specified thermodynamic energy, as in thermodynamics matter and energy are considered as separate entities

Answer (score 2):

In thermodynamics, any well-behaved quantity of matter generally has a temperature (a measure of average internal energy) associated with it. Therefore, the sole addition or removal of matter from a volume is not accompanied by a change in the energy contained in that volume if and only if the matter transferred has zero temperature; transferring matter at nonzero temperatures is the same as transferring energy. In all reasonable cases then, this is an impossibility.

One might argue that one simply has to remove the corresponding amount of heat as matter of some nonzero temperature is added, or vice versa, but this requires walls that *do* allow energy transfer.

Comment: It seems like in the last paragraph a verb is missing (i guess 'remove'). Furthermore, why shouldn't it be possible to let matter with nonzero from within the system get out,  allowing for a zero net energy exchange?

Comment: Sure, that's a way to have zero net energy exchange. But so is the removal of heat. The point is, the walls are allowing thermodynamic energy (in the form of internal energy) to go through them in any case. Also, it's not like the other categories you mentioned allow similar things. In particular, absolutely no mass transfer is allowed in a closed system, whether the total change in mass is zero or not; an isolated system does not allow any transfer of energy, not just that the net transfer should be zero. If you are looking for similar systems, you may want to apply similar criteria.

Comment: Thanks that's a good comment, though I was also using the fact that because thermodynamics is concerned with the macroscopic developement of a system,  you can't really tell if an isolated system allows absolutely no exchange of mass and energy or if it exchanges it but in a way that the net amount is zero

Comment: If in principle the walls allow mass or energy transfer, then in any reasonable case you should be able to arbitrarily supply any amount of mass or energy. It may only be for a particular process that you can have such overall zero transfer. For example, in open systems, you can have processes in which there is no mass transfer, or even no net mass transfer, but this does not fully characterize the system.